# Substitute for CreateDirectory or Path.Combine in Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, environment-variables

CreateDirectory and Path.Combine doesn't seem to work on Windows 8 applications. How could I substitute it?

My first intention was to create a folder inside %APPDATA%, but

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

(something like that, I don't quite remember) doesn't work on Windows 8 apps. So I tried to get the documents library by using

```
KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary
```

but I don't know how to create a folder inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentsLibrary` returns a storage folder:

```
StorageFolder documents = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
```

Now the StorageFolder, or maybe I should say its interface, [`IStorageFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227123) has a method `CreateFolderAsync` with two overloads. The simplest one:

```
StorageFolder newFolder = await documents.CreateFolderAsync("MyDir");
```

Other overload specifies the behavior when there's a directory name collision.

Comment: getting error unautrorizedaccessexception. while Im attempting to createfolder in douments directory . do you know why?